# How does AWS sagemaker model registry metrics visualisation on sagemaker studios work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I am new to Sagemaker and trying to use sagemaker studios as model resgistry and approval platform. But i am unable to understand how does the model version related metrics work.

I have tried registering the model and providing the model metrics json file saved in s3 bucket while passing parameters to create_model_package but i am unable to load the metrics data on the studio dashboard.

Is there a way to integrate them?